# Naming conventions for Azure Policy

Tags: azure, naming-conventions

Azure Policy has initiatives, policy, etc. What naming conventions do you use for these? All the naming conventions I find do not include these. There are even policies to manage naming conventions but not one for the policy itself.

Answer (score 0):

I go with `policy-foo-xyz` and `assignment-foo-xyz`. There is no [official recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-abbreviations) from Microsoft as opposed to other resources.